# Problem with spring aop. How to be sure that interceptor is invoked after commit?

Tags: java, spring, aop, commit, interceptor

I use spring 3.0.5 and with hibernate.

1. Interceptor is working.
2. Send domain id  to jms queue.
3. Consumer recive it and search domain, but is faster than database commit and i get null.
4. How to be shure that interceptor will be called after db commit ?

   appCtx.xml

   ```
   <tx:annotation-driven order="10"  />


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
           <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
       </bean>

   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

   <bean id="domainProducerHandler" depends-on="domainEventService"
           class="org.test.service.DomainProducerHandler" factory-method="aspectOf">
           <property name="domainEventService" ref="domainEventService" />
           <property name="order" value="1" />
   </bean>

   ===================service class=====================
   @SendDomainEvent
   @Transactional
   public ProtoMessage sendDonation(String aa) {
      Domain domainObj = new Domain();
      domainRepository.saveAndFlush(domainObj);

      return domain;
   }


   ==================interceptor class===================**




       @AfterReturning(
       pointcut="@annotation(org.test.service.SendDomainEvent)",
       returning="retVal")
   public void processDomainReturn(Object retVal) {        

   ....

   try {       
       domainEventService.publishToQueue(endDonationSuccessEvent);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       log.error("error during send endDonationSuccessEvent: " + e);
   }
   ```

   }

Interceptor class implements Ordered interface. I set order parameter to tx:annotation-driven order="10" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "order parameter"? The supported ways of [ordering advice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) in Spring AOP are with the [@Ordered annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) or the [org.springframework.core.Ordered](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) interface, which also defines constants for the highest and lowest priorities.